# Select only the first and the last link in divs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a structure like the following:

```
<div class="navigation_sub_item_background" id="sub_nav_2">
    <div class="navigation_sub_item" id="2_1">
        <a  class="navigation__sub__link" href="?p=2_1">
            <span>
                Test 3
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation_sub_item" id="2_2">
        <a  class="navigation__sub__link" href="?p=2_2">
            <span>
                Test 4
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation_sub_item" id="2_3">
        <a  class="navigation__sub__link" href="?p=2_3">
            <span>
                Test 5
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation_sub_item" id="2_4">
        <a  class="navigation__sub__link" href="?p=2_4">
            <span>
                Test 6
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I want to select only the first link and the last link. I tried `div.navigation_sub_item > a.navigation__sub__link:first-of-type` but this selects all of the links.

Anyone a suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Selecting the first and last link

As your links are wrapped in `div` elements you'll need to select the first and last `div` and target the first or last `a` element within those:

```css
.navigation_sub_item:first-child a:first-of-type {
    /* The very first link. */
}

.navigation_sub_item:last-child a:last-of-type {
    /* The very last link. */
}
```

Note that I've specified the `first-of-type` and `last-of-type` on the `a` elements themselves just in case more than one `a` element exists within your `div` elements. You may want to replace these with `first-child` and `last-child` if you do not care about other elements coming before or after them.

---

## A special case for where only one element is present

> I want them all, thats cool. But what should I do if there is only one `.navigation__sub__link-element`? then the :last-child rule will be applied but I want another rule to be used.

In that case you can override the specificity of these selectors by specifying *both* `first-child` and `last-child`:

```css
.navigation_sub_item:first-child:last-child a {
    /* This will override the above selectors. */
}
```

Or if you're not specifying `:first-of-type` or `:last-of-type` on your `a` elements, you could equally use the `:only-child` selector:

```css
.navigation_sub_item:only-child a {
    /* This will also override the above selectors. */
}
```

Comment: ... or leave them out entirely if every `div` is guaranteed to only have one `a` child.

Comment: @BoltClock it's usually not a good idea to make assumptions like that. There's not really any harm in narrowing it down just in case.

Comment: I think it's a fairly reasonable assumption to make judging by the example given in the question - you are similarly assuming that the only possible children of `.navigation_sub_item_background` are `.navigation_sub_item` elements. But then again, it also depends on how someone might interpret "first and last link" as in the title.

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
.navigation_sub_item:first-child .navigation__sub__link {}
.navigation_sub_item:last-child .navigation__sub__link {}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try to this demo example  here  used to first-child, last-child**

```
.navigation_sub_item:first-child .navigation__sub__link,
 .navigation_sub_item:last-child .navigation__sub__link{
  // here style 
}
```

```css
.navigation_sub_item:first-child .navigation__sub__link{
color:red;
}

.navigation_sub_item:last-child .navigation__sub__link{
color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation_sub_item_background" id="sub_nav_2">
    <div class="navigation_sub_item" id="2_1">
        <a  class="navigation__sub__link" href="?p=2_1">
            <span>
                Test 3
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation_sub_item" id="2_2">
        <a  class="navigation__sub__link" href="?p=2_2">
            <span>
                Test 4
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation_sub_item" id="2_3">
        <a  class="navigation__sub__link" href="?p=2_3">
            <span>
                Test 5
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation_sub_item" id="2_4">
        <a  class="navigation__sub__link" href="?p=2_4">
            <span>
                Test 6
            </span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select the first and last child in the following way

```
.navigation_sub_item:first-child .navigation__sub__link,
.navigation_sub_item:last-child .navigation__sub__link {
 /*CSS rules*/
}
```

You can read more about CSS3 [`first-child`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) and [`last-child`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) selectors
by clicking on the links.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `:first-child` and `:last-child`

```
.navigation_sub_item:first-child a,
.navigation_sub_item:last-child a {
    color: red;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/batcave/zw94b74u/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.navigation_sub_item:first-child .navigation__sub__link
```

and

```
.navigation_sub_item:last-child .navigation__sub__link
```

to cover your comment consider this:

```css
.navigation_sub_item:first-child .navigation__sub__link{
  font-weight: bold
}
.navigation_sub_item:last-child .navigation__sub__link{
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation_sub_item_background" id="sub_nav_2">
    <div class="navigation_sub_item" id="2_4">
        <a  class="navigation__sub__link" href="?p=2_4">Test 6</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Snickbrack beware that these selectors will select *all* `.navigation__sub__link` elements within the matching `.navigation_sub_item` elements. As mentioned in my answer here you may want to also specify `first-of-type` and `last-of-type` on those as well.

Comment: @Trix I want them all, thats cool. But what should I do if there is only one `.navigation__sub__link`-element? then the `:last-child` rule will be applied but I want another rule to be used. Is it also possible or should I use JS for that?

Comment: @Snickbrack: Do you need to special-case that? If so, `.navigation_sub_item:only-child .navigation__sub_link`.

Comment: if there is only one `.navigation__sub__link` element, that would be `last-child` and `first-child` at the same time

Comment: @Trix no, at my working example only the `:last-child` is applied

Comment: @Trix: Which is precisely why the last-child rule will override any properties also declared in first-child.

Comment: @Snickbrack please look at updated answer. as u can see both `first-child` and `last-child` are applied

Comment: last-child rule will override any properties also declared in first-child, because it is how css works. if there is something u don't want to be overridden make it `!important`

Answer (score 0):

i think the best method and working for me

```
.div-selecter a:last-of-type { color:red;}
```